# Split an excel content and display in console ignore Blank Cell

Tags: java

In my Excel cell I've data as below. And it is in a single cell.

```
01/2015 to present
02/2010 - 04/2010
01/2008 - 12/2009
```

I want to split this cell and display result as

```
Date 1 - 01/2015 to present
Date 2 - 02/2010 - 04/2010
Date 3 - 01/2008 - 12/2009
```

I'm not sure of how many different lines of data will be in a single cell. There may be up to 10 Lines, then it should print the same like in the below format

```
Date (counter) - (Date Value)
```

Thanks for the hint @Saurabh

I'm using the below code now. and able to print the dates in the above format.

```
if (!covDate.equals(null) || !(covDate == "")|| !(covDate == null) || !covDate.equals("")) 
{
        String[] date = covDate.split("\\n");
        for(int i=0;i<parts.length; i++){
         System.out.println("Date "+ i + " - "+date[i])
        }
}
else{
 System.out.println("Dates Missing");
}
```

Here Basically I've 2 columns in my Excel and in the second column I've these dates. And there are instances where in there is data in `first column` but data is missing in `Dates` column. And there it is throwing me a `null pointer Exception` Also in my eclipse my `else` block is showing error as a `dead block`

please let me know how can i fix these.

Thanks

Comment: can you share your effort, are you able to read the values from the excel. you can then split the content based on "\n" and print then as per your requirement

Comment: Hi @SaurabhJhunjhunwala, Thanks for the hint, added the code and updated my Question. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your test expression below, the date variable inside the for loop is replaced with parts :

```
if (covDate != null && !covDate.equals("")) 
{
    String[] parts = covDate.split("\\n");
    for(int i=0;i<parts.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Date "+ i + " - "+parts[i])
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("Dates Missing");
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have copy/pasted your code without checking variable inside the for loop. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not such a long ternary operator, instead you can use, `StringUtils.isEmpty(object)` ..

This is available in `org.apache.maven.shared.utils.StringUtils`. Once you have this, you can read the object to this method, and perform accordingly.

Secondly, coming to second column, you can try, `if(StringUtils.isEmpty(cellValue))` if this gives you true, then go ahead and split the string, else continue.